# Recovering a JPEG image with broken sections

Tags: data-recovery, file-recovery, jpeg, repair, forensics

Some files were corrupted while being recovered from a disk drive, including portions of videos and images. They all seem  to share the trait of having sections of data replaced with repeating bytes (picture below for reference)
[image: Hex dump]
Moreover, some offsets at certain addresses seem to be broken as well (filled with 00's), but I'm not sure about them
[image: Hex dump]
This is how the image looks like when opened:
[image]
Is there any way to repair the broken image files? If so, what are the options? Is the 00 filled offsets section broken? How does a small section corrupt the rest of the following image data?

Comment: It seems to me that during a transfer from one device to another, the file was pre-populated with zeros/repeating pattern, and the transfer was interrupted at some point.  The best source for the photo would be the original device, or at least an earlier one in the chain of devices.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage The files were acquired in recovery of deleted data from a disk image, so there are really no more sources.

Answer (score 0):

Could you upload the original broken file somewhere (use a service that does not compress the image), so google drive, or dropbox would do.

In general, if the data is interrupted only it is possible to repair these. The higher res, the better the result. Apart from patching or editing the raw data some photo editing may be required too.

[image]